# QGIS Distance Matrix Output is always consists of zeros?

Tags: qgis, distance, distance-matrix

I have a shapefile with 35 points and I try to have the distance matrix showing the distance of each pixel with each other.
I choose the input and the target file the same and the unique ID fields are the names of these points. I try different combinations of output matrix type and number of nearest target points but every time I got the matrix that I intended but all values are zeros.
My shapefiles CRS is EPSG: 4326, WGS84.
I'm just sharing one of the attempts screenshot:
[image]

I can not figure out what if there is something wrong or something missing.

I've also tried the same procedure with changing the CRS to WGS84 UTM zone 36 and ED50 UTM zone 36 but I did not succeed in getting any numbers. I've also tried enabling the on the fly with the same CRS (WGS84) and my projects Measurements Ellipsoid was the same CRS (WGS84). The results are the same table with all zeros.

[image: Example output:]

Comment: Change the projection of your data to meter projection like UTM as an example and then use Distance matrix.

Comment: @ahmadhanb I've also tried it with EPGS:32636, WGS 84/UTM zone 36N and the result was the same.

Comment: Have you tried to load the Projected data in a new QGIS project. So that it can read the `EPSG:32636` correctly?

Comment: how far are your points supposed to be ?

Comment: @ahmadhanb I've opened the shapefile in new qgis project and the result was the same. O even disable the on the fly projection from the project properties. My points distance should vary from 15 to 600km.

Comment: Stay on WGS84 crs, open Project properties, choose crs tab enable on the fly projection choose  WGSS84 as system.
change tab to general, set wgs84 as Ellipsoid under Measurements

Comment: @AndreasW.Bartels I've enabled the on the fly option with WGS84 and my project was already set to Ellipsoid for Measurements under the general tab. But still, I got the same results table.